# Can you alter the default display behaviour for numeric values in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

We have a workflow for exporting data and loading it again via a portable file based mechanism (File Geodatabase and ESRI ArcCatalog). I understand that the underlying problem I have is with this mechanism, however as this workflow has always correctly worked with our Oracle implementation, it has never really been noticed as an issue before.

The issue is that we deliver data in a file geodatabase format (an ESRI GIS format). This format does not allow the storage of precision and scale attributes for numeric values. When data is exported out of this format into Oracle or MS SQL Server (via another ESRI product called ArcCatalog), the numeric columns are created with default scale and precision values (i.e. 38,8).

The rub is that in Oracle if you query the data, it will still display the underlying numeric data in the format as it was held in the file geodatabase. That is, a NUMBER(38,8) will still display as 42.1.
This means that for years, nobody has ever noticed an issue with this approach.

We're now trying to use the same workflow to allow loading into MS SQL Server. However in that platform, this same number will be stored as NUMERIC(38,8) but will when queried display as 42.10000000.

I understand that the correct way of addressing this is to correctly set the scale values, but we have no control over the underlying delivery mechanism. The other way would be to fix it by script once the data is loaded, but there are a lot of columns of varying decimal places to fix after import via script. I'm hoping there is a simpler way to make MS SQL Server display these via some database level setting, or whether we need to account for this in the application (again, ideally we'd avoid that).

Any help or comments appreciated.

Comment: When you mean display do you mean in SQL Server Management Studio? You could use a different tool to run your queries.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't "_display_" anything. It's your SQL client that displays those value, so you need to configure _that_, not the server

Comment: Thanks both. Yes, I guess the symptom is apparent in SQL Server Management Studio; but the issue is a problem in our ArcGIS application that displays the data in various places (including the native ESRI tabular viewer, or our own built code). Is this something that is likely configurable in the client? (if so, any tips for where I might look)